# Using RVM to install Ruby WITHOUT sudo

Tags: ruby, makefile, rvm

In trying to install ruby 1.9.2, I get the error:

```
    Error running 'make -j8',
    please read $HOME/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p320/1372884536_make.log
    There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Then the log says:

```
    gcc: Internal error: Killed (program cc1)
    Please submit a full bug report.
    See  for instructions.
    gcc: Internal error: Killed (program cc1)
    Please submit a full bug report.
    See  for instructions.
    make[1]: *** [callback-5.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    make[1]: *** [callback-4.o] Error 1
    gcc: Internal error: Killed (program cc1)
    Please submit a full bug report.
    See  for instructions.
    make[1]: *** [callback-2.o] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory `$HOME/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p320/ext/dl/callback'
    make: *** [mkmain.sh] Error 1
```

Any idea why I am getting this error? I am running Debian 5.0.9 lenny

---

Answer:
I discovered that the problem was with running make with 8 threads (make -j8). For some reason this does not work on my system. To solve the problem I ran the following function before running `rvm install 1.9.2`:

```
make() { if [[ $@ == "-j8" ]]; then command make -j4; else command make "$@"; fi; }
```

What this does is whenever `make -j8` is ran, the function will replace it with `make -j4`
If this still does not work, you can just run make normally with the following function:

```
make() { if [[ $@ == "-j8" ]]; then command make; else command make "$@"; fi; }
```

Comment: I remember when I installed `rvm` and studied their installation instructions (at http://rvm.io) they were quite specific on doing the installation a certain way in order to be able to use `rvm` without `sudo`. Perhaps double check your `rvm` installation steps and see if there something amiss there.

Answer (score 2):

RVM by default uses number of threads equal to number to CPU cores, you can override the number of threads on command line:

```
rvm install 1.9.2 -j 1
```

this will use only one thread for compiling ruby and seem safest bet if compilation fails with multiple threads.